# Java Generics With Lower Bound Wildcard

Tags: java, generics

I've been reading the Java 8 OCP book by Sybex and I can't seem to understand why the third line doesn't compile.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<? super IOException> exceptions = new ArrayList<Exception>();
     exceptions.add(new Exception()); // DOES NOT COMPILE
     exceptions.add(new IOException());
     exceptions.add(new FileNotFoundException());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Exception` doesn't inherit from `IOException` while `IOException` and `FileNotFoundException` does.

So the [hierarchy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html) is:

```
Exception
   IOException
       FileNotFoundException
```

So, `FileNotFoundException` is an `IOException`, but  `Exception` is Not.

Comment: I feel like this does little to answer the question. I believe the true problem here is the usage of `super`. And even then, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java) should answer that quite well.